# How can I change the color dynamically in listview base on the value from xml parse?

Tags: java, android

Here's I want to code.

Pay the girl = 100 the value of the 100 (100 is the value from XML file in the browser) = is color red

Pay the girl = 200 the value of the 200  (200 is the value from XML file in the browser) = is color green

Pay the boy = 100 the value of the  100 (100 is the value from XML file in the browser) = is color red

Pay the boy = 200 the value of the 200 (200 is the value from XML file in the browser) = is color green

Where if higher value from the XML file in the browser like 200 the color of 200 in the list-view is green while the lower value from the XML file in the browser like 100 the color of 100 in the list-view is red. the value its is change depends in the XML file in the browser. I'm using DOM parser to get the value of pay the boy and pay the girl and I'm using also Timer to auto refresh it in seconds. How can I put the code of my asking changing color in my code XML parse with timer? I do some thing in that but I'm failed.

here's the code

```
@Override
         public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          Timer autoUpdate = new Timer();
          autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                 quotesXMLParsing parser = new quotesXMLParsing();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_item);
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_price, parser.getValue(e, KEY_price));
                    map.put(KEY_pay of the girl, parser.getValue(e, KEY_pay of the girl));
                    map.put(KEY_pay of the boy,  parser.getValue(e, KEY_pay of the boy));


                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems.add(map);
                }

                // Adding menuItems to ListView
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Activity.this, menuItems,
                        R.layout.showquotes,
                        new String[] { KEY_price, KEY_pay of the girl, KEY_pay ogf the boy }, new int[] {
                                R.id.price, R.id.pay of the girl, R.id.pay of the boy });

                setListAdapter(adapter);
             }
            });
           }
          }, 0, 5000); 
         }
}
```

here's the XML file

```
<items>
<item>
<price>100</price>
<pay of the girl>100</pay of the girl>
<pay of the boy>200</pay of the boy>
</item>
```

the value like 100 and 200 change every 5 seconds

here's I tried the code but I failed.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Activity.this, menuItems,
                        R.layout.showquotes,
                        new String[] { KEY_price, KEY_pay of the girl, KEY_pay ogf the boy }, new int[] {
                                R.id.price, R.id.pay of the girl, R.id.pay of the boy });               


            ListAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder1());           
            itemlist.setAdapter(ListAdapter);



 class MyViewBinder1 implements ViewBinder 
 {      @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object Status,String textRepresentation)
            {       
                  String complet="Pay of the girl:+higher ";
                  String complet1="Pay of the boy:+higher";
          String notcomplet="Pay of the girl:-lower";
                  String notcomlet="Pay of the boy:-lower";


                  String getdata= textRepresentation;


                    if((view instanceof TextView) & (Status instanceof String) )
                    { 
                            TextView iv= (TextView) view;     
                            if(complet.equals(Status))
                                {
                                r1=true;
                                r2=false;
                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);       
                            iv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));                
                            return true;
                           }   
                            else if(notcomlet.equals(Status))
                            {
                                r2=true;
                                r1=false;
                                iv.setText(textRepresentation);       
                                iv.setTextColor(Color.RED); 
                                return true;
                            }

                            if(r1 && (getdata.startsWith("Pay of the girl:   ")))
                           {                            

                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);      

                            iv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));                           
                            return true;
                           }
                if(r1 && (getdata.startsWith("Pay of the boy:   ")))
                           {                            

                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);      

                            iv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));                           
                            return true;
            {
                        else if (r2 && (getdata.startsWith("Pay of the girl:   ")))
                        {
                            //TextView iv= (TextView) view;
                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);       
                            iv.setTextColor(Color.RED);                              
                            return true;
                        }
            else if (r2 && (getdata.startsWith("Pay of the boy:   ")))
                        {
                            //TextView iv= (TextView) view;
                            iv.setText(textRepresentation);       
                            iv.setTextColor(Color.RED);                              
                            return true;                           
                    }        
                  return false;
            }           
}
```

here I want to ask how to? this images.as an reference

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you please post the code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: heres the code xml parse with timer

Comment: there is a wrong part in your XML. <pay of the girl>100</pay of the boy>, it should be <pay of the girl>100</pay of the girl>

Comment: You will only have two prices or can be more?

Comment: @Milos what did you mean item of my listview ?

Comment: If you mean Item in my listview yes can be more

Comment: @user1645696, yes I mean items in your listview. Use the custom adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what are your requests, I can propose you to use a custom ListAdapter for your listview with one property element which is the background. Then, when you are populating the listView, for each element you should set the background (red or green).

If you would like to learn about custom ListAdapters, here is the link http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx

Remember that the custom ListAdapter extends the BaseAdapter.

If you need more help about, feel free to ask me.

Comment: you mean I change my simple adapter alternate custom Listadapter?

Comment: Exactly, instead of using the Android SimpleAdapter, you could use your own custom ListAdapter and change the bacground in there. Custom adapters are maybe hard to understand for the first time but once you get in, it is really powerfool and you can manage your lists as you want (add images, subitems etc...)..

Comment: ok I understand you, but If I choose Custom Listadapter, then my code above is change also or not? :)

Comment: @JAL, yes, your code will change a litle bit. You don't need anymore the MyViewBinder1 class. Then, you have to create your custom adapter class, the custom adapter xml file and set the custom adapter to your listview. Your List Array should have one additional value which is for example backgroundColor. For more info on how to do it, use the website I gived you, or look for some additional info by ggogling custom ListAdapter Android

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it and if you have more questions about the custom list adapter, please open a new question and put the link here, I will help you with..

Comment: about my xml parse it can be change? thank you very much I will ask you if I have some problem :)

Comment: Your XML parse ??? I don't understand you. No problem, please feel fre to ask me if you have further questions.

Comment: which is I call my XML file. first code above. I mean If I change my adapter so I need to change my code to call my XML file? sorry I don't know what is the term?

Comment: Ah ok. In fact, you have to create first a listView in your XML file, then you have to declare how it looks like your list item in another xml file. Then, you have to create a custom adapter class where you will populate your class. Then, in your main activity whre you have the data, you have to set your custom adapter.

Comment: @JAL, Of corse, I can help you, but not in that question. Please, confirm the answer as the right one and start a new question "How to use custom list adapter for android" and give me the link here, I will give you a detailed example.

Comment: @ milos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525785/how-to-use-custom-list-adapter-for-android

Comment: Thank you. I will prepare the solution for you. Can you please check my answer as the right one.

Comment: You got the answer for the other question.